# Get react state with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already know how to setState with a dynamic key name but how do I set a value as the state with a dynamic key?

Example

```
function thing(key) {
 let stuff = this.state.key;

 //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother! Didn't even think of accessing it that way! It was a duplicate.

Comment: If you could accept it as a duplicate (by following the directions on the yellow dialog) that'd be great!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Didn't even think of think of this as first but all I did was

```
function thing(key) {
 let stuff = this.state[key];

 //Do stuff
}
```

and it worked!